# Best Practice To SQL Query, INSERT, DELETE From CSV In S3

Tags: sql, csv, amazon-s3, sql-delete

I currently have csv's in my S3 bucket that I would like query and run inserts and deletes into. I know this can be done using maybe pandas in python, but I was wondering if there was a preferable way to be able to modify csv's in S3 and pretty much treat them like tables?

Comment: Does the database product you're using support external tables? [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Comment: why not use some online spreadsheet solution? the google ones allow you run queries on them